# Is it possible to use one preamp distortion into 2 amplifiers at the same time?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, distortion

I have a Diezel VH4-2 pedal and a Radial ABY switch. If I use the VH4-2 pedal power amp out will the two outputs from the ABY switch be connected to the return/loop of both amps? Is this possible? I just wanted to use the full capacity of the vh42 as a preamp.

Comment: The main question is: is ABY able to tolerate and transmit preamp level signal? Radial support should help you with understanding that. If not, you can connect it to line out of VH4-2, but then it might not be as loud as you wish. Other than that, is there any advantage of using VH4-2 pedal over using the preamp section in your actual VH4 amps? Or if you have VH4, and another amp, you can use ABY to connect to VH4 directly, and to the other amp via VH4-2 and into return loop. Not exactly what you wanted... but maybe better, as you can set two preamps differently?

Comment: Thanks. I'm planning on using it on 2 different amps. Let me reach out to radial support as well

Comment: Could someone explain how this is a duplicate of that question?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the Diezel VH4-2's "to power amp in"  to the input of the Radial ABY switch and the two outputs from the ABY switch to the return/loop of both amps. This would allow you to use the VH4-2 as a preamp and route your signal to either one or both amps. Make sure the levels and impedances of the connections are compatible to avoid problems.